# How do I pull these commits off my master branch and into their own branch, so I can merge them later?

Tags: git

The commits since `origin` have NOT been pushed.

[image]

I did not plan very well, and realized that `Targeted Interests` and `Appodeal` are big commits that touch a lot of code and could potentially break things, so I would like to move those commits off my master branch and into their own branch, planning to merge them in at a later date.

How would I do this?

Comment: I don't have the time to write up a complete answer, but here's an outline: Create a new branch at `origin/master`, cherry-pick the commits in question thither, and then use `git rebase` in interactive mode to remove the commits from your `master` branch. You *can* also accomplish the latter by creating a temporary branch and cherry-picking all *but* those two commits thither, and then replace `master` with that temporary branch.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Thanks! I learned how to `git rebase -i` today! So powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you need to follow.

1. Create a new branch `feature_branch` at `origin/master` and check it out.
2. Cherry pick `Appodeal` and `Targeted interests` into `feature_branch`.
3. Create a new branch `temp` at `Fix Android linking` and check it out.
4. Cherry pick all the commits in `master` branch above `temp` except the commits you need to put aside, into `temp` branch.
5. Hard reset `master` branch to the same commit `temp` is pointing at.
6. Delete `temp` branch.

Before starting, it is better to create a new branch at the commit where `master` branch is pointing at, so it will be easier to recover if you do something wrong. Also, backing up the repository before doing anything is also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. At `master`, `git branch backup-appodeal` in case I screw up.
2. At `origin/master`, `git checkout -b appodeal`.
3. At `appodeal`, `git cherry-pick` the commits I want to move from `master`.
4. At `master`, `git rebase -i` to `drop` the just cherry-picked commits, which were moved to `appodeal`.

[image]

Voila!

[image]